# C++ - geometric primitives class hierarchy

Tags: c++, encapsulation, data-hiding

I'm new in C++, and I would like to work on my first tutorial.

I want to write a program which shall implement search over a list of objects representing graphical symbols.

The list contains Rectangles, described by two edge lengths, and circles, described by radius.

I also want to create a search procedure, that takes in a list and rectangle edge length and returns another list containing only these symbols that fit into the given rectangle.

Implementation of the list (and the search function) should allow to
extend the list of accepted symbols (e.g. add polygon) without modifying
any of the existing code.

What kind of approach should I follow? Could you give me a similar example to my aim?

Comment: Read this - there are many good examples here for you. http://gillius.org/ooptut/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a use for polymorphism - you'll have `std::vector<Object*>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>>` to hold the list of objects.

Object should essentially look like this:

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual ~Object() = default;

    // needs to be implemented by deriving classes i.e. Rectangle and Circle
    virtual bool fitsIn(Rectangle const& r) const = 0;
};
```

And of course `Rectangle` and `Circle` will inherit from it:

```
class Rectangle : public Object
{
    int x, y, w, h;

public:
    Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) : x(x), y(y), w(w), h(h) {}

    virtual bool fitsIn(Rectangle const& r) const override
    {
        // return whether can fit in r based on this object's and r's x, y, w and h
    }
};
```

Then you'll be able to add it into the list, iterate through and call `fitsIn` on every element, pushing it to the other vector depending on what `fitsIn` returns:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> objects, fitting_objects;

objects.push_back(new Rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20)); // classic polymorphism spectacle

// rectangle for the area containing the objects we're looking for
Rectangle r(5, 5, 30, 30);

for(auto const& object : objects)
    if(object.fitsIn(r))
        fitting_objects.push_back(object);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time LogicStuff. I appreciate your help. Could you give me an example how can I add rectangle to the list with which parameters? And if I want, how can I extend my list with a polygon? Thanks.

Comment: @yusuf Are you familiar with polymorphism? It'll be better for you if you look it up, rather than me posting an almost-complete code.

Comment: Yes, I know polymorphism, but have never used in c++. I have learned polymorphism with Java. But if I see this example, it would be very convenient for me to go forward quickly.

Comment: Ok, give me a second.

Comment: Thank you LogicStuff. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you Logic Stuff. Do you have an idea how can I make in a way that the user will be able to add polygon afterwards without modifying the code?

Comment: Well adding another type of object means modifying the code. It means adding `class Polygon : public Object { ... };`, what would you expect?

Comment: I see. In this case, instead of Rectangle class, I may rename the class as polygon, and implement inside. Thank you.